# Is there any alternative for object in html5, because one of the object attribute classid is not working in html5

Tags: javascript, html, razor

In normal html4 this object tag working.

```
<object id="AIO" name="AIO" classid="clsid:B1FD4D17-1C9E-44B7-9B63-A2F6AE4ED836"></object>
```

In Html5 same code is not working because of the classid attribute. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: How does it fail? Have you considered switching from the invalid/nonexistent `classid` to the valid `data-classid`?

Comment: Try to replace `classid="GUID"` with  `type="Content Type"`, e.g. `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"`. This is still valid in HTML5.

Comment: Thanks David. But data-classid is not working.